# Nginx Problem: Nginx adds comma and duplicate the url

Tags: apache, http, nginx, flask, gunicorn

I've just deployed a flask application with Gunicorn and Nginx. The application is running under 192.168.25.49 address. Nginx configured as following:

```
server {
   listen 80;
   server_name 192.168.25.49;

        location / {
            include proxy_params;
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_set_header host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-real-ip $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-forward-for $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_pass http://unix:/home/avin/Saba/saba.sock;
          }
 }
```

The problem is: When I enter 192.168.25.49 in the address bar, it automatically changes to http://192.168.25.49,192.168.25.49/login. This problem occurs on login and logout too.

I've searched whole the internet but nothing found for this problem. If anyone with Nginx knowledge help me will appreciate.

Comment: I do not see where the problem can come from Nginx. Could your flask app be redirecting you ?

Comment: I tested this hypothesis before. Flask + Gunicorm works properly without Nginx. The problem occurs when Nginx becomes enable.

Comment: Hi did you fix this?

Comment: Hi @philoj. Yes, I did. Just modify /etc/nginx/proxy_params and comment proxy_set_header Host $http_host; line. Goodluck